# Retrofit: 500 internal server error

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I have 500 internal server error, every time when i try to send POST request via Retrofit. When i sending GET request, it sending correctly. I'm sure that with serverside everyting is ok. What's wrong with my code ?

```
    String ENDPOINT = "http://52.88.40.210";
    //model for request
        FriendModel ff = new FriendModel();
        ff.setFriendNumber("380935275259");
        ff.setId(516);
        ff.setNumber("380936831127");

        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .build();
        WayfAPI api = adapter.create(WayfAPI.class);
        api.getFriendsLocation(ff, new Callback<List<FriendLocationModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<FriendLocationModel> friendLocationModels, Response response) {
                for (FriendLocationModel ff : friendLocationModels) {
                    Log.d("myLogs", "===========Successful==========");
                    Log.d("myLogs", "Id: " + ff.getId());
                    Log.d("myLogs", "Number: " + ff.getNumber());
                    Log.d("myLogs", "GeoLocation: : " + ff.getGeoLocation());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d("myLogs", "-------ERROR-------");
                Log.d("myLogs", Log.getStackTraceString(error));
            }
        });
    }
```

Declaration of request:

```
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-type: application/json"
})
@POST("/api/geo/getLoc")
public void getFriendsLocation(@Body FriendModel friendModel, Callback<List<FriendLocationModel>> response);
```

Exampe of request and response from Postman: 
[image]

Comment: It seems that in postman you're sending an array of FriendModel, but in your code you're sending a single object. What does the server expect to get?

Comment: @UdiI Thak you for answer, yes, server side can't recognized single JSON object. I can modify serverside and teach it to recognized single JSON object, but this is bad idea. Becouse, more request - more resource using on serverside. I need to know how i can send request with array of JSON objects via Retrofit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that in postman you're sending an array of FriendModel, but in your code you're sending a single object.

Just change the object you're sending, and instead of sending a single object, send a List as the server expects

```
    List<FriendModel> friendsList = new ArrayList<FriendModel>();

    FriendModel ff = new FriendModel();
    ff.setFriendNumber("380935275259");
    ff.setId(516);
    ff.setNumber("380936831127");

    friendsList.add(ff);
```

You should also change this signature:

```
public void getFriendsLocation(@Body FriendModel friendModel, Callback<List<FriendLocationModel>> response);
```

to

```
public void getFriendsLocation(@Body List<FriendModel> friendModel, Callback<List<FriendLocationModel>> response);
```